# Merging two ASF files

Tags: model-view-controller, visual-c++, directshow, msdn, windows-media-encoder

I have an ASF file which contain 8 audios and 1 video. Now i want to merge this file with other of same ASF type. Is it possible to do with windows media SDK.
My language is VC++

Please give some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably yes. Depending on stream formats and used codecs in the first and second files this can be done with or without re-encoding. See samples (wmvcopy, WMVRecompress) in Windows Media Format SDK. And you do not need to use DirectShow.